# how to redirect the hyperlink in a new tab or(new window) when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome

here is the step:
1.when a user click a 'a' tag
2.prevent Default  'a' event(before link to a new url,we need to do sth)
3.if the user login,do nothing.
4.if not login, redirect the hyperlink to a login page.

the question is how to keep the orgin url and after do so judgement,and  redirect the hyperlink to the url saved before?

i use window.open(url),but the chrome browser will block the action.

here is the code

```
E.on(selector,'click',function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
      var href = this.href;//save the url
         //send ajax 
      var tag = 999919047; 
         S.io.getScript("setTag.do?tag="+tag,function(data){
             if(data.code==0){
                 window.open(href);
              }
           else
             { 
               hrefStr = "login.jhtml?f=top&redirectURL=http%3A%2F%2Ftemai.html";
               window.location.href=hrefStr;
              }



         });




      });
```

thank you very much.
^_^

Comment: Try disabling pop up blocker in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Try using target="_blank" in the anchor tag. This will open the link in a new tab or window depending on the browser settings